# Extract text without conditional lookahead in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I would like to extract the text in **bold** using Java regex support.

I could get it working using conditional lookahead, with the regex being

`(\d{2})(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s+(\S+)\s+(?(?=.*\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})([^\d{4}]*)|(.*))`

However, Java Pattern class doesn't support conditional lookaheads. Is there a way to rewrite the regex so that it works with Java Pattern class?

**160203 03:24:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql**2016-02-03 03:24:25 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).2016-02-03 03:24:25 0 [Note] /opt/devenv/mysql/mysql-5.6.27-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27) starting as process 29491 ...2016-02-03 03:24:25 29491 [Note] IPv6 is available.

**160203 21:33:17 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0**

**160203 21:33:17 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted**2016-02-03 21:33:18 1125 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 33062016-02-03 21:33:18 1125 [Note] IPv6 is available.

Comment: You should clarify your rule to extract text. Ex, it's must be start of line or sth.

Comment: Sure, should have mentioned that. I want to pick up all the text uptil the first occurence of a date patttern similar to 2016-02-03 OR till the end if the pattern isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a tempered lookahead:

```
(?:(?!\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}).)*
```

This matches everything up to (but not including) the next thing that looks like a date, or the next line end, whichever comes first.  It does this be checking each character before it's consumed to make sure it's not the first character of a date.  To use this in Java:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(?m)^(\\d{2})(\\d{1,2})(\\d{1,2})\\s+(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2})\\s+(\\S+)\\s+((?:(?!\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}).)*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    // matched text: m.group()
}
```

The `(?m)^` makes sure each match starts at the beginning of a line.

I should note that this is not equivalent to your conditional, but I think it's what you really wanted.  Maybe it's okay with you, but given this hypothetical input:

```
160203 21:33:17 mysqld_safe process1 restarted2016-02-03 21:33:18 1125
```

...your regex stops before the `1` in `process1`.

The `[^\d{4}]*` in your regex is apparently meant to stop at the next four-character sequence, but it really stops any character that's not one of `{`, `}`, or a digit.  Of course, it only does that *after* the lookahead has determined that there's a date up ahead.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I don't have much idea about tempered lookaheads. How should I use the expression you gave to extract my text (in BOLD)? I tried combining your expression with mine, something like                (\d{2})(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s+(\S+)\s+(?:(?!\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}).)*. However, it does not give me the full text.

Comment: Everything that's matched by the regex (the bolded text in your samples) will be in group(0).  I've added some code to demonstrate (`group()` and `group(0)` are equivalent).

Comment: Okay, I see now. However, I would ideally want to capture multiple groups.  I already have 7 capturing groups before this tempered lookaround. Whatever text appears after that (uptil the date pattern OR end of string) should be captured as group 8. Anyway that could be accomplished?

Comment: Sure, just wrap that last part in another capturing group.  I've edited my answer to add the group.